# How does one use ActiveRecord with views and user-defined functions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm wondering what the proper way to do these two things is, if there is any.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ActiveRecord isn't really designed with views and stored procs in mind. It works best with fresh databases and it really expects the logic to stay in Ruby. If you have to work against an older database, then you can Google using Rails with legacy databases. In addition, one of the other ORMs (DataMapper, maybe something else) may work better with legacy databases

Comment: This isn't a legacy database, it's a new database. I happen to LIKE user defined DB functions -- they work great! :)

Comment: That's fine. Rails is picky, it's designed to not like views and DB functions. If you want to use them, it would be easier to use a different framework and ORM

Comment: What do you mean "Rails doesn't like views"?  Rails treats views just like a regular table, except you can't read from it.